# How to make Excel Sheet Visible Programmatically in C#?

Tags: c#, excel

I am developing an Excel Report in C#. I have the input and the configuration settings in the Excel file and I generate the output report in Excel as well.

So, there will be 3 Excel Files open in the program. So, this is how I do it through single `Excel` object :

```
Excel._Workbook inputWb = oXL.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFileName, misval, misval, misval, misval, misval, misval, misval, misval, misval, misval, misval, misval, misval, misval);
Excel._Worksheet inSheet = inputWb.Sheets["Input"];

Excel._Workbook configWb = oXL.Workbooks.Open(ConfigFile, misval, misval, misval, misval, misval, misval, misval, misval, misval, misval, misval, misval, misval, misval);
Excel._Worksheet configSheet = configWb.Sheets[1];

Excel._Workbook outputWb = (Excel._Workbook)(oXL.Workbooks.Add(misval));
Excel._Worksheet outSheet = outputWb.Sheets[1];
```

Now, I would like to make just the output Excel file Visible. Any idea how do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`oXL.Visible = true;` should show the Excel file you are dealing with.

Comment: It will make all the 3 Excel files visible. I would like only output referred to by outputWb in my program visible.

Comment: Then you have to create 3 different Excel application objects. oXL1, oXL2 and oXL3.

Comment: WorkSheet also has a Visible property.

Comment: @HansPassant, Ya, That's right. But the output file was not visible still.

Comment: But he wants to show a whole workbook (= Excel file) and he has 3 workbooks associated to the same Excel application object.

Comment: @varocarbas, Ya, Is there a better way to do it ?

Comment: If you want to create three different workbooks it is the same than creating three different Excel files and thus three different Excel application objects. What is the problem with creating three oXLs? What you can do is putting everything in the same workbook and just relying on different worksheets, but this is a different story.

Comment: @www.sapnaedu.in just to make completely sure that you understand how the Excel automation works: if what you want are different worksheets ("tabs" in the same Excel file), you have to rely on the Excel._Worksheet object and you can hide/show them or whatever you want. All the sheets in a file are associated to a workbook and this workbook to an Excel application; from the external point of view, both realities (workbook and application) form the Excel file you see. Thus if you associate various workbooks to the same application, all of them will have to be shown/hidden at the same time.

Comment: @varocarbas, Thank you so much for you help. I understand now. I was wondering if it is possible to selectively hide/show for the workbook to a single Excel application.

Comment: @www.sapnaedu.in understand that, from the point of view of what you see, workbook and Excel application are basically the same. The only practical use of having the two different realities (Excel application and workbooks) is being able to do the same with various files at the same time (e.g., showing/hidding them). If you want to treat different files, differently, you have to associate a different Excel application to each of them; in any case, this is not too difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide individual worksheets, but you can also hide a workbook. In VBA:

```
    Workbooks(2).Windows(1).Visible = False
```

or

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:My Documents\Hide Test.xlsx"
Windows("Hide Test.xlsx").Visible = False
```

Change this setting to `True` before saving or closing the workbook (if appropriate).